# Windows 7 Temporary Profiles on New PC's

Tags: windows-7, active-directory, user-profiles, windows-domain, exchange-2010

2 new ASUS Pro laptops, i5, 4GB RAM etc. Windows 7 Professional.

Im trying to set them up onto our domain. I ran through the name change and domain join procedure through my computer -> right click -> properties -> etc, the same way its done every time.

Both machines do not load a user profile for the user that its going to be for, they load a temp profile every time?! Both the users are new (over 24 hours old) and one of them already has a company laptop which works with his profile.

I've taken both laptops off of the domain and re-joined, no luck. I've run through the list of profiles in reg-edit but obviously as these users haven't logged onto these machines before, its not showing them in the list.

I'm joining them to domain via ethernet cable not wireless as I know wireless has issues.

Unsure what else to try.

Thanks
Jamie

Comment: Not quite sure why you've tagged this question with "exchange" as this problem is not Exchange related. Anyway: have the machines had a pre-fabricated image applied or has Windows been installed from scratch on both machines? I've experienced an image that had the "copyprofile" setting enabled in a sysprepped image that caused us the same problem. We had to re-create our image.

Comment: My mistake, think I automatically clicked what it suggested out of habit.

Pre-fabricated image from asus on both. Ive found that running through the "join domain" process again but using the wizard, produces a message of Access Denied (tried using local and domain admin)

Currently looking at the possibility of a LDAP replication issue? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/330095

Comment: When you created the machine in AD did you set the user/group as to who can actually add the machine to the domain - in response to your "access denied". If you didn't then you'll need domain admin credentials to add the machine.

Comment: Elaborate? The machine isn't added to AD manually as it should be picked up automatically (which it has been) Before the machine is on the domain it uses its local admin account. Joining the domain, domain administrator account is used.

Comment: Also I can logon to the machines perfectly fine with domain administrator accounts. (without temp profiles) but any other domain account logs on as a temp.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer seemed to be changing the entry for "profile path" in AD to a logon script.

Very odd...

Comment: ignore the above, i've realised I was being an idiot.

Profile Path....we dont bloody have profile paths here! 

Schoolboy Error....